# Shopify collection products images do not show

Tags: image, collections, shopify

Im working on a clients website and i am absolutely stumped on what the issue could be. The shopify collection products images for the default collection template do not show, but on other collections they do!

I have reviewed the source code for all the collection templates and i see no error. The link below leads to one of the products in the collection that has the error

[Product Link](https://bagatelle.city/products/metallic-faux-leather-biker-1)
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Cay you share the `liquid` you've written?

Comment: this is a link to the code that was in the theme for product.template
https://jsfiddle.net/jmpb9hcq